# Encryption on Android

Tags: android, encryption, jasypt

I am using [Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org) on Android to provide encryption functionality.

I use it to hash passwords under SHA-1 and am looking to use it to encrypt binary data

Jasypt currently uses PBEWithMD5AndDES

I don’t know a great deal about PBEWithMD5AndDES but understand its not secure enough to be storing sensitive data such as the data I will be storing (passwords, usernames, etc……..)

Should I stick with PBEWithMD5AndDES or look to use another encryption algorithm?

I also understand PBEWithMD5AndDES is the only algorithm supported by Android and I would have to look to a third party API for this

Answer (score 1):

Personally I prefer using bouncycastle on android for encryption.
You can make your mind up with symmetrical (AES etc) or asymmetrical encryption (RSA, etc).